# Can I get a refresh token using Auth0 passwordless lock in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, auth0, password-less

I'm using version 2.2.3 of passwordless lock. I have the following code within a function:

```
var lock = new Auth0LockPasswordless("CLIENT_ID", "AUTH0_DOMAIN");
lock.emailcode({autoclose: true}, function (error, profile, id_token, access_token, state, refresh_token) {
    if (!error) {            
        console.log(refresh_token); //undefined
    }
});
```

When this code is invoked, state and refresh_token return undefined.

I've tried adding `authParams: { scope: "offline_access"} }` to the options, but that stops my login from working

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `authParams: { scope: "openid offline_access", response_type: 'token'}}`

Comment: That worked Shrek! I now have a refresh token! Happy to accept your comment as the answer if you want to post